# How to "Outset" the pattern using Inset Tool

Tags: edit-mode

I am struggling to perform an Outset move with the inset tool on this pattern. It needs to be outset by 10. I have removed duplicates but doesn't seem to make a difference.
I have attached the model for convenience.

[image]

[image]

Any suggestions? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way that I know is extrude this face up, then use shrink\fatten (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) to outset the thing, then remove one face back.

[image]

If you don't mind using add-ons, you may activate add-on "Mesh Tools", and use a function offset edges from this add-on (context menu ⇾ Mesh Tools ⇾ Offset Edges)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this! Excatly what I needed and the 2nd option is also great to know!

Answer (score 2):

Do you need an interior edge loop, or do you just need to enlarge the mesh.  You can accomplish either by first scaling the mesh to make it larger, and then using the inset tool to make the inset face, if you need it:

[image: how to scale and then inset]

Comment: Thanks for this. Crantisz got there first so Il mark his answer.